# ORA-00920 invalid relational operator

Tags: java, oracle

I created a class (Execute_Query_Bd_Multiples_Results) to connect to DB and execute a query in DB Oracle.

This class (Execute_Query_Bud_Multiples_Results) returns 2 values (int Id_Estrategia1 and int Id_Estrategia2) that are passed to the (Connect) method.

In the (Connect) method there is a variable called ls_command that receives the query value and returns the result of the query to the main class (Executar_Query_Bd_Multiplos_Resultados).

In the test class (Executar_Query_Bd_Multiplos_Resultados_Test) I make the method call (Connect) and pass two values to the method (319, 179) and print on the screen. 
The Eclipse console displays the following error message: ORA-00920 invalid relational operator.
I do not know why this error message. Below is the class code.

```
public class Executar_Query_Bd_Multiplos_Resultados {
//Variáveis de BD
Connection conOracle = null;
Statement stmtOracle = null;
ResultSet rsetOracle = null;

public String Conectar(int Id_Estrategia1, int Id_Estrategia2) {

    String retorno = "#;-1;@";

    Boolean lb_continuar = true;
    //StringBuilder ls_comando = new StringBuilder();
    String ls_comando = new String();

    try {
        System.out.println("Conectando ao banco de dados Oracle...");
        String url = "";
        try {
            //conectando aos bancos de dados
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.5.12.116:1521:desenv01";
            DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(10);
            conOracle = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, "bkofficeadm", "bkofficeadmdesenv01");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("falha SQL >> " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println("falha geral >> " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            lb_continuar = false;
        }
        //String teste = "'BKO - Rep Conectividade'";
        if (lb_continuar) {
            System.err.println("Preparando comando...");
            System.out.println("");

            ls_comando = "SELECT  DS_ESTRATEGIA, ID_ESTRATEGIA"+
                                  " FROM TB_BKOFFICE_ESTRATEGIA"+
                                  " WHERE ID_ESTRATEGIA  IN" + Id_Estrategia1+"" +Id_Estrategia2+"";    
            System.out.println(ls_comando);

            stmtOracle = conOracle.createStatement();
            stmtOracle.setQueryTimeout(10);
            rsetOracle = stmtOracle.executeQuery(ls_comando.replaceAll("\n", " ").trim());

            if(rsetOracle.next()) {
                retorno = rsetOracle.getString(1);
            }              
            rsetOracle.close();
            stmtOracle.close();             
            /*
            Para comandos de Insert, Delete, ou Update
            --------------------------------------------------------
            stmtOracle = conOracle.createStatement();
            stmtOracle.setQueryTimeout(10);
            stmtOracle.execute(variavel_comando.toString());
            conOracle.commit();
            stmtOracle.close();
            */
        } 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro - " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rsetOracle != null) {
                rsetOracle.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao fechar rset - " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            if (stmtOracle != null) {
                stmtOracle.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao fechar stmt - " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            if (conOracle != null && !conOracle.isClosed()) {
                conOracle.close();
            }
            if (conOracle != null && !conOracle.isClosed()) {
                conOracle.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao fechar con  - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

}

public class Executar_Query_Bd_Multiplos_Resultados_Test {

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    Executar_Query_Bd_Multiplos_Resultados qr_2 = new Executar_Query_Bd_Multiplos_Resultados();
    String codEstrategias = qr_2.Conectar(319, 179);
    System.out.println("Estratégias: " + codEstrategias);

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void test() {

}
```

}

[Erro - ORA-00920](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au9x8.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add  (  ) around in elems and , for separation

```
"SELECT  DS_ESTRATEGIA, ID_ESTRATEGIA" +
" FROM TB_BKOFFICE_ESTRATEGIA" +
" WHERE ID_ESTRATEGIA IN (" + Id_Estrategia1 + ", " + Id_Estrategia2 + ")";
```

Comment: Okay scaisEdge. The ORA-00920 invalid relational operator message was not displayed by Eclipse, but the class result also did not appear. Eclipse returned the following result:Estratégias: #;-1;@.

Comment: this mean that the main sintax error is solved   but Id_Estrategia1 and Id_Estrategia2 which data type are ?   number of string?

Comment: scaisEdge, I pass 2 integers to the Conectar method and hope that the method returns a String. The data exists in the table but Eclipse does not display the query result in the window.

Comment: if the value of Id_Estrategia* are string you should wrap the value in the IN clause with single quote  ..

Comment: scaisEdge are integers. The variable retorno that is String.

Comment: then check if  the   values for  Id_Estrategia1 and Id_Estrategia2  are correct .and check for your data content . seems a problem related  to your data  and not related  to the code  ..  you have not error message so i thinks that my answer had solved  your original question  ..

Comment: I think the problem is in the query. I had Eclipse print on the screen the value assigned to the variable ls_comando which is the variable that receives the SELECT result, and what was displayed in the Eclipse console was: SELECT DS_ESTRATEGY, ID_ESTRATEGY FROM TB_BKOFFICE_ESTRATEGY WHERE ID_TRANSEGORY IN (319179).

Comment: I am passing to the method Conectar 2 integers (319, 179) but the query is understood to be a unique number (319179). The result of the SELECT returns null and therefore is displayed on the #; - 1; @ screen.

I do not know how to make the query understand that there are 2 different numbers. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your question is about the Oracle error code ORA-00920 invalid relational operator.  and this seems solved to me .. then looking to your sql comment in the comment above  the code seems weel formed (the IN clase contain a value and is close between brackets)  so check if have properly written the code as  in my answer ..  ..and last the fatc the error message is gone mean that you are asking for another question .. and this is not in SO rules ... justa a question ny time  ...  not question or comment that extend question

Comment: and as in your code  you have omitted the comma between the two id you must use (" + Id_Estrategia1 + ", " + Id_Estrategia2 + ")" not (" + Id_Estrategia1 + "" + Id_Estrategia2 + ")"

Comment: Okay the query worked but only brought 1 result. You should have brought 2 results. See below the query return in the Eclipse console.

SELECT  DS_ESTRATEGIA, ID_ESTRATEGIA FROM TB_BKOFFICE_ESTRATEGIA WHERE ID_ESTRATEGIA  IN (179, 319)
Estratégias: Facilidades